# In Java, does adding/subtracting/multipying/dividing a primitive type to a boxed type create a new object of the boxed type?

Tags: java, autoboxing

```
Integer x = new Integer(5);
x = x + 1;
```

For the above snippet, is a new Integer object created when the operation `x = x + 1` is performed?

Comment: `new Integer object`, do you mean that `x` isn´t refering to it´s original `x` reference, then yes (`immutable`). If you mean that it doesn´t refer to the cached `Integer` with the value `6`, then no(cached `Integer` range).

Comment: I'd use `Integer.valueOf()` to get cache values; the compiler may do it, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happens:

`x` is `Integer` in `Integer x = new Integer(5);` - *note, there will be no new objects here, object from Integer cache will be used!*

Now, `x + 1` performs. In order for that to happen, `x` becomes `int` (unboxing), and you now how `int` of value `6`, which is placed in **temporary variable**.

Next, boxing will happen for `=`. Since `Integers` are cached from `-128` to `127`, your `Integer` of value `6` will not be created, but `x` will point to object `Integer(6)` in that cache. When we talk about values outside of that range, new object will be created. If you had before for `x` an `Integer` object with value outside of that range, that object would be deleted by GC when it decides to.

Comment: Am I wrong to think that if you use new keyword you will have a new instance?. From Integer src. 
`    /**
     * Constructs a newly allocated {@code Integer} object that
     * represents the specified {@code int} value.
     *
     * @param   value   the value to be represented by the
     *                  {@code Integer} object.
     */
    public Integer(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
`

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**

***Unboxing*** will be happing when arithmetic operators appears,

```
    Integer x = new Integer(5);
    x = x + 1; //1) Unboxing will happen to int 5. 2)Addition happens 
                            3)Reboxing to new Object -- this will create new Object
```